# Thread does not start in a Swing application

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I am working on a relatively simple DB manager, that takes in a number of files, parses and catalogs the information in a particular fashion. I also wrote a simple GUI in Swing for this purpose. In order to speed up the process I want to implement multithreading to the parallelizable parts of the execution in order to speed up the program.

The below code sits in a class called `FDBCreatePanel`, a custom `JPanel`, that sits in a `FDBManagerFrame` which accommodates the main method.

```
private void dbCreateActionButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_dbCreateActionButtonActionPerformed

    jfc = new JFileChooser();               
    jfc.setVisible(true);
    jfc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int returnVal = jfc.showSaveDialog(null);
    ((FDBManagerFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(this)).startProcessAnimation();

    if(returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        new SwingWorker<Void,Void>(){
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                File dir = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                DbManager dbm = new DbManager(dir, dbNameField.getText());
                try{
                    dbm.doTimeConsumingStuff();

                } catch (SQLException e){
                    // errorhandling
                } 
            @Override
            protected void done() {
                ((FDBManagerFrame) SwingUtilities.getRoot(FDBCreatePanel.this)).endProcessAnimation();
            }
        }.execute();
    }       
}
```

The time consuming method in `DbManager` class leads to (among others) the following bits of code in the `ParserType1` class:

```
private void init() {
    try {
        this.reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(this.datfile));
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Entry e;
                while((e = parseNextEntry()) != null)
                    queue.offer(e);
            }           
        }, "t1-parser-thread");
        t.run();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // error handling
    }
}
```

I do not see any `t1-parser-thread`(s) in JVisualVM when I monitor the execution of my program. It appears as if my code executes entirely on a single thread, ignoring the initiation of new threads. Am I missing something with respect to threading and Swing?

Comment: Your `ParserType1.init` method doesn't start a new thread. It calls `run` on a `Thread` object, when I suspect you wanted to call `start`...

Comment: @JonSkeet nice catch... pretty embarrassing mistake on my part. Although I have to ask why both `run()` and `start()`? I mean is there any reason why one would call `run()` instead of `start()`

Comment: Most people who have done threading have made this mistake. ;)

Comment: @posdef: It was a design mistake in making Thread implement Runnable, IMO :(

Comment: @JonSkeet I see... Thanks for the insight and the answer! If you could perhaps reformulate your two comments into an answer I could accept it as you were first with the answer to the question. :) Otherwise, if you can't be bothered I'll just accept jeremyjjbrown's answer

Comment: Ah, I see the second half of the question has been removed - that's why I hadn't answered before, because that looked like it *was* creating a thread pool.

Comment: @JonSkeet it did, apparently... There was another small mistake there which I discovered as I was re-reading my question, thus I edited quickly and removed the bits regarding the thread pool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `run()` on the newly created `Thread` object in `ParserType1.init()`. That doesn't start a new thread - it just execute's the thread's `run()` method in the existing thread. You should be calling `start()` instead.

Fundamentally I think it was a mistake for `Thread` to implement `Runnable` at all - the distinction between "this is the code that should be executed" (`Runnable`) and "this is the way I'm going to execute it" (`Thread`) has been unfortunately blurred. The fact that `Thread` *can* also compose a `Runnable` makes it even worse.

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() { ... };
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable) {
    // Override run here...
};
```

Unless your overridden `run` method calls `super.run()`, the `Runnable` passed into the constructor is ignored. Crazy stuff. `Thread` should (IMO) be final, not implement `Runnable`, and *force* you to provide a `Runnable` at construction. It's far too late to change now, unfortunately :(

Basically, you should *never* be calling `run()` on a `Thread`. At least, I can't remember the last time I saw that without it being a bug.

Comment: Interesting, I thought this would certainly be the key problem, but I am re-running a test now and the "t1-parser-thread" is nowhere to be seen, even after `t.start()`... Peculiar

Comment: @posdef: Maybe it started but finished quickly?

Answer (score 1):

As Jon Pointed out you want to call the start() method to actually spawn a new Thread which will call the run method of your inline Runnable. If you just call run it is like you called any other method and it will execute in the same Thread.

```
}, "t1-parser-thread");
    t.start();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html